# Is it possible to create an expandablelistview with dynamic holder view heights?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to develop an Android App where I need to implement an ExpandableListView in which the holder views can have different heights according to the content of the specific holder view. As an iOS developer, I am pretty familiar with doing it with UITableView but I'm having trouble knowing how this can be done with Android. Anything can be helpful. Thanks!

Best,

Comment: keep the view height to wrap_content and it will adjust automatically according to content

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: Thanks, guys! Yeah, I've looked at this library. So basically it can be done just by using wrap_content and while using this library?

Comment: @JoshJoshJosh yes it should work